# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'scrollHeight' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, infragistics

In one of our project, we are using a Infragistics 7.1 and vs2010 before.
Recently after the migration of the project to VS2013 and Infragistics 9.1 started getting the below error.

> get1stElementByName: elm not found.
>
> tag:th, name:thYear

When checked, it was from this code

```
function get1stElementByName(tag, name){
  if(document.all){
    var elms=document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for(e in elms) if(elms[e]&& elms[e].name==name) return elms[e];
  } else {
    var elms=document.getElementsByName(name);
    if(elms && elms[0]) return elms[0];
  }
  alert('get1stElementByName: elm not found.\ntag:' + tag + ', name:' + name);
  return null;
}
```

The function doesn't read the tag and returns null.

And the Tag comes from the `UltraWebTabs`.

I'm not sure why it is not working after migrating from Infragistics 7.1 to 9.1.
After migration am i missing anything. please someone help me on this.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using [`document.all` as it's not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Depending on the browser you need to support you could use ```querySelector``` which would simplify the code (return the first element if using the right CSS query) and may resolve the issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're using is from 2009 and was developed to support browser back then. Since then browsers have evolved and this code has changed a lot. The `UltraWebTabs` control is not supported by `Infragistics` since 2010. My suggestion would be to migrate to the latest version of `Infragistics ASP.NET`, which currently is 15.1, and use the new `WebTab` control which is the modern counterpart of the UltraWebTab and supports all modern browsers.